# back navigation behavior on android

Tags: android, android-activity, back, launchmode

I have some activities in my app:
**A** - Login Activity
**B** - Main app Activity
**C**, **D** ... - Inner Activities
I want to implement a behaviour as follows:

1. when a user select the app icon OR select the app from the task list I want the back stack to be cleared and show Activity **A**
2. when a user passed **A** pressing the back on activity **B** will quit the application
3. when a user in an inner app pressing back will function "normally".

for example: activity stack **A** -> **B** -> **C** -> **D**  pressing the back button the first time (top activity is **D**) will make pop the **D** of the stack top and it will be: **A** -> **B** -> **C** clicking again (top activity is **C**) will move us to **A** -> **B** and clicking again will quit the app (as described in 2)

I implemented (2) by adding `android:noHistory="true"` to **A**'s properties in `AndroidManifest.xml`
and tried to implement (1) by adding `android:launchMode=singleTop` to  **A**'s properties in `AndroidManifest.xml` but when I do that (3) is breaked and clicking back when  **D** is visible moves me directly to **A**.

how can I implement them all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Detect Back Key presses:

```
 @Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
      if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
          //Do what you want, forinstance:
          finish(); //This will close the current Activity and will go back to the previous one
          }

      return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }
```

To close **D** you can use `finish();` like in in the top example. This will close **D** and will bring you back to **C**.
Same with **C** and in **B** you normally shouldn close the App. 
But if so, you could call somtehing like `System.exit(0);` to close the App.

To define, which Activity is the parent Activity, go into the Manifest.xml and put things like this:
This is for your 1. thing:

```
      <activity  
       android:name=".ActivityD" 
       android:parentActivityName="com.example.ActivityA" >
       <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.ActivityA" />
       </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override onbackpressed method and used intent

```
> Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
> intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
> intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
> startActivity(intent);
```

On activity b